# How to make ajax calls across domains?

Tags: java, json, ajax, spring-mvc, cross-domain

I am using the code below for making an Ajax call.  The call is going to a JAVA controller but is unable to fetch the data, throwing this error:

```
error: 406 format not supported.
```

I am using spring 4 and sending data in jSON format.

```
$.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:url,
            contentType:"application/json",
            dataType:'jsonp',
            crossDomain:true,
            data:data,
           jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
            success:fnSuccess,
            error: fnError
        });
```

Comment: what is the format of the data returned?

Comment: using JSON format. String format also not working.